# PSTCKPaymentCardTextField not displaying on view

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway

Trying to integrate Paystack with my app. Using PSTCKPaymentCardTextField as described in the [guide](https://github.com/PaystackHQ/paystack-ios/blob/master/GUIDE.md), but it just doesn't display anything on my view when I run the app.

```
import UIKit
import Paystack


 class PaymentViewController: UIViewController, PSTCKPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {

 let paymentTextField: PSTCKPaymentCardTextField = {
   let ptf = PSTCKPaymentCardTextField()
    return ptf
 }()

 func setupPaymentTextField() {
    let paymentFormWidth = self.view.frame.width - 30
    paymentTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: paymentFormWidth, height: 44)
    paymentTextField.delegate = self
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(paymentTextField)
    setupPaymentTextField()

  }

}
```

Am i doing something wrong? Please help me out.
Thanks

**Note: I am new to swift language**

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem? If not, check out Rave's IOS plugin. You should find it easier to implement. https://flutterwavedevelopers.readme.io/v1.0/docs/ios

Comment: @OlufemiIsraelOlanipekun I haven't found a solution to this problem yet, I don't want to use Rave's iOS plugin, because it has to be Paystack, we use Paystack for the other platforms, so iOS cant be different.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved!. Used auto-layout instead of using `paymentTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: paymentFormWidth, height: 44)`

```
func setupPaymentTextField() {
    paymentTextField.delegate = self

    paymentTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    paymentTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    paymentTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    paymentTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
}
```